# Release iPhone App iOS7

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7

I developed an iPhone app that works on iOS 6 and iOS 7 but not in iOS 5 or iOS 4.3
I want to release this app to App Store. 
Will the store reject my app because it is not work in iOS 4.3 or the Store accepts the apps that work on iOS 7 as its the new thing?

Hope anyone got my mean.

Comment: Just working on `iOS 6` and `iOS 7` is absolutely fine they will not reject it.

Comment: That's what **Deployment Target** is used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is just for `iOS 6` and `iOS 7` that is fine it will just be restricted to device with that iOS on them. As long as you have set your `Deployment Target` to be 6.0 it will work fine and not be rejected. And unless your app goes against the [Apple Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html) you will be fine.

**Additional note that isn't in the guidelines**

Your app must work on retina 4 inch (iPhone 5) otherwise it will be rejected.

Good luck with your submission.

Answer (score 1):

No problem with that. Keep your deployment target as iOS 6.0. That will be fine